# Show/hide divs on hover dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On the moment I am building code to show text when I hover on a certain `div`. I am able to produce this, but it's static and I can't reproduce it. I would like to make it dynamic. I have a single function that recognizes which photo you are hovering over and shows the `div` that belongs to it. What I've tried is as shown below:

**HTML**

```
<div class="member-photo glenn">
    <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">
    <div class="member-text member-glenn">
        <p class="member-name">Glenn</p>
        <p class="member-function">developer</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.member-glenn {
   display: none;
}
```

**JQuery**

```
$(".glenn").hover(function(){
    $('.member-glenn').show();
},function(){
    $('.member-glenn').hide();
});
```

What I would like is to replace all occurrences of **glenn** (my name) with a default of **class/id**.

Comment: why not directly use .member-glenn{display:none} and glenn:hover>.member-glenn{display:block} no need to ids and jquery

Comment: could you use better, jquery find by text tag, better than use jquery query by classname, is that you want?

Comment: you may use ".mouseout()"  and "mouseover()" JQuery events .. for example check snippen @ Aman kumar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No javascript needed!

```js
//$(".glenn").hover(function(){
//    $('.member-glenn').show();
//},function(){
//    $('.member-glenn').hide();
//});
```

```css
.member-glenn {
   display: none;
}

.glenn:hover .member-glenn {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="member-photo glenn">
        <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">

        <div class="member-text member-glenn">
            <p class="member-name">Glenn</p>
            <p class="member-function">developer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

For more photos no change:

```css
.member-glenn {
   display: none;
}

.glenn:hover .member-glenn {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="member-photo glenn">
            <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">

            <div class="member-text member-glenn">
                <p class="member-name">Glenn 1</p>
                <p class="member-function">developer 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="member-photo glenn">
            <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">

            <div class="member-text member-glenn">
                <p class="member-name">Glenn 2</p>
                <p class="member-function">developer 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="member-photo glenn">
            <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">

            <div class="member-text member-glenn">
                <p class="member-name">Glenn 3</p>
                <p class="member-function">developer 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="member-photo glenn">
            <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">

            <div class="member-text member-glenn">
                <p class="member-name">Glenn 4</p>
                <p class="member-function">developer 4</p>
            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="member-photo glenn">
            <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">

            <div class="member-text member-glenn">
                <p class="member-name">Glenn 5</p>
                <p class="member-function">developer 5</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now maybe it shouldn't be jumping arround which is a positoning issue which can be fixed with positioning

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}
.glenn {
  position: relative;
}

.member-glenn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25px;
  display: none;
}

.glenn:hover .member-glenn {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<div class="member-photo glenn">
            <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">

            <div class="member-text member-glenn">
                <p class="member-name">Glenn 1</p>
                <p class="member-function">developer 1</p>
            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="member-photo glenn">
            <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">

            <div class="member-text member-glenn">
                <p class="member-name">Glenn 2</p>
                <p class="member-function">developer 2</p>
            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="member-photo glenn">
            <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">

            <div class="member-text member-glenn">
                <p class="member-name">Glenn 3</p>
                <p class="member-function">developer 3</p>
            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="member-photo glenn">
            <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">

            <div class="member-text member-glenn">
                <p class="member-name">Glenn 4</p>
                <p class="member-function">developer 4</p>
            </div>
        </div>


    <div class="member-photo glenn">
            <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">

            <div class="member-text member-glenn">
                <p class="member-name">Glenn 5</p>
                <p class="member-function">developer 5</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Now your boss might says: "Oh but it should have a fade effect" still **no javascript needed**

```css
p {
  margin: 0;
}
.glenn {
  position: relative;
}

.member-glenn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 25px;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  transition: all 0.75s ease;
}

.glenn:hover .member-glenn {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="member-photo glenn">
                <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">

                <div class="member-text member-glenn">
                    <p class="member-name">Glenn 1</p>
                    <p class="member-function">developer 1</p>
                </div>
            </div>


        <div class="member-photo glenn">
                <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">

                <div class="member-text member-glenn">
                    <p class="member-name">Glenn 2</p>
                    <p class="member-function">developer 2</p>
                </div>
            </div>


        <div class="member-photo glenn">
                <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">

                <div class="member-text member-glenn">
                    <p class="member-name">Glenn 3</p>
                    <p class="member-function">developer 3</p>
                </div>
            </div>


        <div class="member-photo glenn">
                <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">

                <div class="member-text member-glenn">
                    <p class="member-name">Glenn 4</p>
                    <p class="member-function">developer 4</p>
                </div>
            </div>


        <div class="member-photo glenn">
                <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">

                <div class="member-text member-glenn">
                    <p class="member-name">Glenn 5</p>
                    <p class="member-function">developer 5</p>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: @Gijsberts you are welcome. If you want to see how close you where with your attempt this is how you could have finish it. https://jsfiddle.net/hgc70y6c/2/ but really, don't use javascript if you can solve it without.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example if your having more than 1 person on your page at once.

```js
$(".member-photo").hover(function() {
  var value = $(this).data("value");
  $('.member[data-value="'+value+'"]').show();
}, function() {
  var value = $(this).data("value");
  $('.member[data-value="'+value+'"]').hide();
});
```

```css
.member-text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="member-photo" data-value="glenn">
  <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">

  <div class="member-text member" data-value="glenn">
    <p class="member-name">Glenn</p>
    <p class="member-function">developer</p>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="member-photo" data-value="Nick">
  <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">

  <div class="member-text member" data-value="Nick">
    <p class="member-name">Nick</p>
    <p class="member-function">developer</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Carsten. I downvoted and here is why: 1. No reason for jQuery/javascript. 2. if you use jQuery/javascript don't make it more complex! There is no need for `data-attributes` and value changes see [here](https://jsfiddle.net/hgc70y6c/2/) how it could be solved with jQuery even it is bad for this task

Answer (score 2):

### User Jquery Mouse events

```js
$(function() {
  $('#hover_Id').mouseover(function() {
       $('#effect').removeClass('member-glenn');
    });
  $('#hover_Id').mouseout(function() {
       $('#effect').addClass('member-glenn');
    });
});
```

```css
.member-glenn {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="member-photo glenn" id="hover_Id">
        <img src="images/retouched/glenn-round-transparant-not.png" class="img-responsive">

  <div class="member-text member-glenn" id="effect">
            <p class="member-name">Glenn</p>
            <p class="member-function">developer</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
$(this).hover(function(){
    $('.member-text').show();
},function(){
    $('.member-text').hide();
});
```