# jquery animation for fadein and fadeout

Tags: jquery, html

I'm gonna add the animation for div tag such as fadein and fadeout.
When the user putting the mouse on the div tag, that one will be faded out.
When the user putting the mouse out of the div tag, that one will be faded in.
This is test code.

```js
          $('#div1').mouseleave(function(){
            $('#div1').fadeIn();
            console.log("out");
          });

          $('#div1').mouseover(function(){
            $('#div1').fadeOut();
            console.log("in");
          });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">hover over me</div>
```

But when the user put the mouse on the div tag, the animation is repeated.
How could I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is if you `:hover` and `fadeOut()` what happens is the element becomes `display: none;` (you will see in my example the green box) so when it is `fadeOut()` the element is not there anymore and so the `mouseleave` gets called. To fix that issue is to hide a child element and keep the parent (`orange box`) so the mouse is still over the parent `#div1` ...

```js
$('#div1').mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).children('.fade-me').fadeIn();
  console.log("out");
});

$('#div1').mouseover(function(){
  $(this).children('.fade-me').fadeOut();
  console.log("in");
});
```

```css
#div1 {
  background-color: orange;
  padding: 10px;
  min-height: 20px;
}

#div1 > div {
  background-color: green;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <div class="fade-me">hover over me</div>
</div>
```

You know that you can do this with `CSS` only? Let me know if you need a `CSS` only example.

Comment: @AndrewLi yes. Look at this answer I just wrote yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42020198/2008111 let me know if you don't get along with that one and need a specific example with your markup.

Comment: But I think there is no animation. I'd like to add animation.

Comment: @AndrewLi see in that answer the last snippet where I wrote: `Now your boss might says: "Oh but it should have a fade effect" still no javascript needed `

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't have to use jQuery here! You could use plain CSS.

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  transition: 1s opacity ease; /* this here makes sure that all changes to the "opacity" element happen over 1 second. */
}
div:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  Aravind!
</div>
```